# Send Token to Random Addresses

Tags: addresses, randomness, sendtransaction, mint

First of all, is this the right way to send a token to a random address?

`_mint(address(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(now))), _amount)`

If so, how do I make it to repeat itself 10 times (sending a token to 10 random addresses)?

Comment: We could write a for loop

Comment: Hi hinanily! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! I'd recommend against doing this. There's less than 200M addresses used, from a maximum `256^20`. So the probability to randomly send tokens to a used address are `1.36 * 10^(-40)`, almost zero.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

You randomness generation will not work. You rely on `now` (alias of `block.timestamp`, the timestamp when the block including your transaction was mined, https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties), which is not going to change in your loop.

Instead, you could derive 10 different public keys, see ChainLink randomness expansion for instance : https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf-best-practices/#getting-multiple-random-numbers

The way to do it 10 times is to include it in a loop (in a for loop for instance :

```
for(uint256 i=0; i<10; i++) {
  _mint(address(uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(now, i))));
}
```

Or, for every Solidity version, including >=0.8.0 not supporting bytes32 to address casting anymore :

```
for(uint256 i=0; i<10; i++) {
  address adr;
  bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(now, i))

  assembly {
    mstore(0x0, hash)
    adr := mload(0x0);
  }

  _mint(adr);
}
```